# SQLite DELETE not working

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm using the following code to remove certain rows from my SQLite table.

```
                if (!cfile.exists()) {// remove invalid db files
                    database.rawQuery("DELETE FROM "
                            + DataBaseHelper.VFS_DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE "
                            + DataBaseHelper.VIRTUAL_SYSTEM_COLUMN_PATH // TODO
                                                // not
                                                // removing
                                                // properly
                            + " IS ?", new String[] { pathcursora.getString(0) });
                    System.out.println("DELETE FROM "
                            + DataBaseHelper.VFS_DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE "
                            + DataBaseHelper.VIRTUAL_SYSTEM_COLUMN_PATH
                            + " IS "+pathcursora.getString(0));
                }
```

But the rows are not getting deleted. Stack trace below:

```
02-28 23:13:27.564: D/NameManager.java(7098): Checking for whatever
02-28 23:13:27.587: I/System.out(7098): 1 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages87
02-28 23:13:27.587: I/System.out(7098): 2 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages3
02-28 23:13:27.595: I/System.out(7098): Invalid db entry for /mnt/sdcard/fsimages3 removed.
02-28 23:13:27.595: I/System.out(7098): 3 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages2
02-28 23:13:27.603: I/System.out(7098): Invalid db entry for /mnt/sdcard/fsimages2 removed.
02-28 23:13:27.603: I/System.out(7098): 4 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages1
02-28 23:13:27.603: I/System.out(7098): Invalid db entry for /mnt/sdcard/fsimages1 removed.
02-28 23:13:27.603: I/System.out(7098): 5 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages
02-28 23:13:46.603: D/NameManager.java(7098): Checking for whatever
02-28 23:13:46.618: I/System.out(7098): 1 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages87
02-28 23:13:46.618: I/System.out(7098): 2 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages3
02-28 23:13:46.626: I/System.out(7098): Invalid db entry for /mnt/sdcard/fsimages3 removed.
02-28 23:13:46.626: I/System.out(7098): 3 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages2
02-28 23:13:46.626: I/System.out(7098): Invalid db entry for /mnt/sdcard/fsimages2 removed.
02-28 23:13:46.626: I/System.out(7098): 4 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages1
02-28 23:13:46.634: I/System.out(7098): Invalid db entry for /mnt/sdcard/fsimages1 removed.
02-28 23:13:46.634: I/System.out(7098): 5 : /mnt/sdcard/fsimages
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Echo your query statement as see how it looks

Comment: @trapper **ECHO :**  `DELETE FROM vs_table WHERE vspath IS /mnt/sdcard/fsimages1`

Answer (score 2):

(Unless you're in auto-commit mode) are you committing your transaction?

Have you checked your SQL statement for accuracy?

Comment: I don't know what that means, I'm only learning sql. How can I commit this transaction?

Comment: **ECHO :**  `DELETE FROM vs_table WHERE vspath IS /mnt/sdcard/fsimages1` Both vspath and entry "/mnt/sdcard/fsimages1" exists

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you need single-quotes around your parameter value, or use a bound variable (preferred).

```
DELETE FROM vs_table WHERE vspath IS '/mnt/sdcard/fsimages1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rawQuery, use the delete() function to effectuate a safe parameterized query:

```
DbHelper hDbHelper = ...;
SQLiteDatabase hDB;
hDB = hDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

hDB.delete (DataBaseHelper.VFS_DATABASE_TABLE, 
        String.format("%s = ?",DataBaseHelper.VIRTUAL_SYSTEM_COLUMN_PATH),
        new String[] {pathcursora.getString(0)});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SQL statement to write database, than use the **execSql() method instead of rawQuery()**!

The rawQuery() function able to execute a Select, and return a Cursor, that contain the query result, but this is not able to write database.

The execSql() function have no return value! If the success of deleting is important use the delete() method.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the issue was resolved when I used the primary key in the WHERE clause of the DELETE command. In my case, I had two columns (together) are set as the primary key so I had to use WHERE column1 = 'value1' AND column2 = 'value2'.

This approach can always be doable by running a query command to get the primary key values for the records that need to be deleted.